# FabricJS canvas to image issue

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I have used Fabricjs on my project. If I draw some thing to canvas it works fine at the time of convert them to `dataurl`. But when I draw any image and convert them to `dataurl` its not working properly.

Can anyone help on this.

Here is my code:

Load canvas from json:

```
CANVASOBJ.canvas.loadFromJSON(CANVASOBJ.canJson.items[k].data, CANVASOBJ.canvas.renderAll.bind(CANVASOBJ.canvas), function(o, object) {

 });
```

Function to convert to blob:

```
var blob =CANVASOBJ.toBlob(imageFileType,CANVASOBJ.canvas);

toBlob : function (type,canvas) {
         var dataN = canvas.toDataURL({
                width: canvas.getWidth(),
                height:  canvas.getHeight(),
                multiplier: ''
            });
            console.log(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
            var data = dataN.replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
            return CANVASOBJ.b64toBlob(data, 'image/png');



    },
    b64toBlob:function (b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
    contentType = contentType || '';
    sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

    var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    var byteArrays = [];

    for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
        var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

        var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }
    console.log(byteArrays);
    var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
    return blob;
}
```

Comment: do you have an error claiming that the operation is insecure or that the canvas is tainted ?

Comment: no.. but if i put any image on canvas and try to save it.. the image on canvas is not coming...

Comment: .I mean the image from the canvas is not coming to output image..

Comment: could you share a working demo ? (well, a live non-working demo actually)

Comment: Please have a look at the video... I hope you could understand the issue..

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/t9tVuE6fKehN

Comment: sorry, I don't have a flash plugin. Can you try to make it work in something like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: it will be great if you can view the video..its a long and complex project. I am also trying to extract the code to show you in jsfiddle.